# ¿Como agregar una propiedad de tipo objeto, en una clase diferente? C#

Tags: c#, herencia, c#-8.0, paso-por-referencia, referencias

agradecería que me ayuden con esto.
Tengo 1 clase que tiene que recibir una propiedad de tipo objeto, no sé como realizar esto.
Lo hice así pero está mal ya que lo que necesito llamar y setear es una propiedad del objeto Categoria, la propiedad de Categoria que necesito es "Descripcion".

```
public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
```

Sé que lo unico que estoy haciendo es referencia a la otra clase llamada Categoria pero lo que necesito es tomar un atributo de esa clase("Descripcion")

Esto lo necesito ya que cuando voy a crear un hidrometro, necesito que el usuario ingrese la Categoria o mejor dicho el atributo "Descripcion" de Categoria para setearlo a la Clase que recibe esta referencia(Es el codigo que hice mal, antes lo enseñé)

```
 nuevoHidrometro.Categoria.Descripcion = textBox4.Text;
 nuevoHidrometro.Cliente.Identificacion = textBox5.Text;
```

Así es como estoy pidiendo los datos, si los pido de esta forma no hay error.
Sin embargo, si lo pido de otra forma, tengo error de que no puedo convertir un tipo objeto a un string.

Espero explicarme bien, gracias.

Les dejo más codigo por si no me expliqué de la mejor forma.

```
public class Hidrometro
{   
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }  
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
```

Tengo esta clase, pero no sé como poner estas 2 propiedad, ya que de esas clases solo necesito, de Categoria necesito un atributo string llamado "Descripcion" y de cliente un atributo int llamado "Cedula"

Tambien les agradezco si me confirman como ingresar los datos, lo estoy haciendo así pero no sé si estoy bien.

```
 nuevoHidrometro.Categoria.Descripcion = textBox4.Text;
 nuevoHidrometro.Cliente.Identificacion = textBox5.Text;
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu error? Ya que justamente como estás seteando los valores de las clases es como se realiza, hay una forma más estética de hacerlo pero en definitiva así es como se asigna valores a propiedades de objetos :)

Comment: Igual nos sirve entender un poquito mas tu problema si pones el código de la clase categoría o cliente

Comment: No me sale ningún error hasta que corro el programa. Me sale esto System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Justamente en esta linea nuevoHidrometro.Categoria.Descripcion = textBox4.Text;

Answer (score 0):

Ya que querian ver la clase Cliente y Categoria

```
 public class Cliente : Persona
{
    
    public string CorreoElectronico { get; set; }
    public string NumeroCelular { get; set; }
```

Como pueden ver la clase cliente es heredada de la clase persona, lo que necesito obtener de esta clase es el atributo "Identificacion", no se ve en esas lineas ya que es herencia de Persona.

Ahora con la otra clase

```
 public class Categoria 
{
    public string CodigoCategoria { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
```

De esta clase necesito el atributo "Descripcion".

Comment: Por favor no utilices el área de respuestas para comentarios o extender la pregunta. Te recomiendo [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/411235/edit) tu pregunta para agregar el código adicional y eliminar lo que colocaste como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

primero instancia y usa el objeto así:

```
var obj = new Categoria(){};
obj.Descripcion = textBox4.Text;
```

Luego ese objeto se asigna a la otra clase así:

```
objHidrometro.Categoria = obj;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!